# How to run text2image.cpp

Tags: tesseract, training-data, text2image

I am working on tesseract. I want create new training language for tesseract. Please can anyone tell me what are the specific steps for training new language. And also tell me how to run text2image.cpp program. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run text2image first compile and link text2image.cpp using an appropriate C++ toolchain then run the executable with the appropriate text file as an input.  Alternatively you can download a windows [installer](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=) which will give you an executable to use rather than the .cpp.

Instructions on building the tesseract tool chain are [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling) and on how to train for currently unsupported languages is [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).

Comment: I compile it in Turbo c++. It gives errors like unable to read library.

Comment: At what stage, what exact error message, which library?

Comment: Error messages like "Unable to read include stdlib"               "Unable to read include sting" "Unable to read include iostream"

Comment: What is your include path set to? Those are all standard libraries - also are you compiling as C or C++ you need to look into the compiler flags.  Instructions on how to build https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling

Comment: Include path is "C:\TC\include" and "C:\TC\lib" and I am compiling it as cpp program. I followed documentation but it can't help me so much. Even I can't run tesseract command from CLI.

Comment: Can you tell me simplified steps to train new language in tsseract? I am using winn xp. And I have text file which I want to convert in ttf.

Comment: When using the windows installer, where is text2image.exe placed?

Comment: The installer should offer you the chance to change it but the default will probably be `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\`